# Incorporating responsive design in Google App Maker

Tags: responsive-design, google-app-maker

I have been looking for an adequate way to make my design responsive and easily used with mobile devices, within google app maker. Using 'auto' for the horizontal width or vertical height does help with this but the resizing of text even using the css font size by vw  results in my content not being compatible with mobile devices and web. Any ideas how to make Google App Maker more 'mobile friendly' so to say, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of all, Hello, welcome to StackOverflow ! Your question is very broad, I think it might help if you provide some examples of code in html/css etc of what you already tried and limit it to a specific part of it. That way others can help you better. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to start with flexible layouts. Panels will adjust to the space available if you set `fit to content` or `fill parent`, and widgets will scale in the space available by setting `minWidth`, `maxWidth`, `minHeight`, and `maxHeight`.

After that, you can design CSS formats that tweak the layout for each screen size you target.

According to the Google App Maker guide for [page styles](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/styles#device_resolution):

> To automatically adjust the layout for different screen sizes, use media queries in your global CSS. For an introduction to responsive design, see [Responsive Web Design Basics](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/). For an example, see [Responsive layout grid](https://material.io/design/layout/responsive-layout-grid.html#).